# Upgrade to 2.7.2 got this error "An Error Was Encountered Non-existent class: Addons"

Tags: upgrade, php-errors, addons

Anyone else seen this error during an EE 2.7.2 upgrade?

> "An Error Was Encountered Non-existent class: Addons"

If I remove installer, the CP error says:

> Your ExpressionEngine installation’s version (2.7.1) is not consistent with the reported version (2.7.2). Please update your installation of ExpressionEngine again.

I updated all the modules to latest versions cannot find anything similar in forums.

Answer (score 4):

If somebody will have the same error - check if you have Solspace FreeForm . I had the same  issue because of this (FreeForm v.4.0.4). Fix - temporary remove freeform folder. You can return it back after update will finish.

Comment: Removing Freeform (4.1.3) add-on files from the third-party folders (system and themes) did the trick for me.

Comment: You don't even have to remove it, just put an underscore before the folder name (`_freeform`). I only  had to do this in the `third_party` folder and it worked. Hiding the `themes` folder wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would try is ensure that all addons (fieldtypes, extenstions, modules, plugins) are updated and then re-uploading the 2.7.2 EE files.

if that doesn't work, you may need to rollback to your backup of the site and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue upgrading to 2.7.3 and thought I should let people know that the removing free form, then pasting it back in after upgrade solution still seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Removing Freeform (and putting it back after the update has finished) works for me still.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/system/expressionengine/config/config.php` and on line 14 or so you'll see `$config['app_version']` and make sure it equals 272 (no periods)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep going that way. After this error you simply can remove installer and the system will be up to date. The version will update and database tables as well.